# Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:Component_A.Binaries' in section 'Fragment:'

Tags: wix3.11

I have two simple console app projects "Component-A" and "Component-B" which I want to include in my SetupWixDemo project in my solution.

In my Wix project file for Setup I have enabled Harvesting project

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnableProjectHarvesting>True</EnableProjectHarvesting>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and included the two projects using HeatProject

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <HeatProject Include="..\Component-A\Component-A.csproj">
      <ProjectOutputGroups>Binaries</ProjectOutputGroups>
      <Link>Component-A.csproj</Link>
    </HeatProject>
    <HeatProject Include="..\Component-B\Component-B.csproj">
      <ProjectOutputGroups>Binaries</ProjectOutputGroups>
      <Link>Component-B.csproj</Link>
    </HeatProject>
  </ItemGroup>
```

It has generated the components wix files correctly
**Generated _Component_A.wxs**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="Component_A.Binaries">
            <Component Id="cmpC008F1473856A259012D9243F2FAA367" Guid="*">
                <File Id="fil76224611BE6FE33E8C4C1CB922BE4507" Source="$(var.Component-A.TargetDir)\Component-A.exe" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp8F2527F5846E0A97DD990421A1BFE039" Guid="*">
                <File Id="fil2887E426D398DC77AF53475EC6CC8E82" Source="$(var.Component-A.TargetDir)\Component-A.exe.config" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Component_A.Binaries">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpC008F1473856A259012D9243F2FAA367" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp8F2527F5846E0A97DD990421A1BFE039" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

**Generated _Component_B.wxs**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="Component_B.Binaries">
            <Component Id="cmpC4EEFA1957E631623A020D230FE7FE27" Guid="*">
                <File Id="fil027682CC235FE3E8DB7E93B17A690B4E" Source="$(var.Component-B.TargetDir)\Component-B.exe" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp5DCF4C7D83433EA092BBF18737C93FB1" Guid="*">
                <File Id="filA4BD1B738072866436267073D1E70237" Source="$(var.Component-B.TargetDir)\Component-B.exe.config" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Component_B.Binaries">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpC4EEFA1957E631623A020D230FE7FE27" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp5DCF4C7D83433EA092BBF18737C93FB1" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

**Product.wxs**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <Product Id="*" Name="SetupWixDemo" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="WK" UpgradeCode="60e5ca62-51b5-47d3-81b5-a36b078c88c5">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"  Platform="x64"/>

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of SetupWixDemo is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupWixDemo" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Component_A.Binaries"  />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Component_B.Binaries" />
        </Feature>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
    <SetDirectory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[WindowsVolume]Apps\WixDemo" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupWixDemo" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I keep getting the following.

Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:Component_A.Binaries' in section 'Fragment:'
Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:Component_B.Binaries' in section 'Fragment:'

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE:**

Found a fix for this error . Realized I need to include both the Directory entry for both components

```xml
    <Fragment>
    <SetDirectory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[WindowsVolume]Apps\WixDemo" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WixDemo" />
        <Directory Id="Component_A.Binaries" Name="WixDemo" />
        <Directory Id="Component_B.Binaries" Name="WixDemo" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    </Fragment>
```

Though now its not installing anything and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Found the remaining issue. It was installing under program files. So had to include SetDirectory tag for each component and that fixed it.

```
<Fragment>
    <SetDirectory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[WindowsVolume]Apps\WixDemo" />
    <SetDirectory Id="Component_A.Binaries" Value="[WindowsVolume]Apps\WixDemo" />
    <SetDirectory Id="Component_B.Binaries" Value="[WindowsVolume]Apps\WixDemo" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WixDemo" />
        <Directory Id="Component_A.Binaries" Name="WixDemo" />
        <Directory Id="Component_B.Binaries" Name="WixDemo" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    </Fragment>
```